# Clarification of how the suggested edit queue works?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

I recently submitted a (still pending edit) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597856/prevent-mobile-on-desktop-like-apple-does), then noticed that I missed something and corrected the issue a few minutes later.

It's a well-known feature that two edits within a short space of time by the same user on the same question are counted as just one edit in the review queue.

If this happens, is the edit bumped back to the bottom of the review queue, or does it keep its place with the previous edit?